# Certificates in docker local registry

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, docker-registry

I'm trying to set up a docker local registry within my university network. Since they offer certificates from rediris I requested one, so I have now three different files:

1. cert.pem
2. intermediate.pem
3. chain.pem

In addition to this, I kept my .key and .csr as well. Following the docker website example (https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate)

```
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt
```

I'm not able to comprehend how concatenate/transform those pem files into the domain.crt file I need, all my tries led to the docker local registry treating the cert as self-signed.

Thank you very much in advance and am really sorry if this question is dumb, my knowledge on system administration is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look inside those files, I think you'll probably see that chain.pem is the concatenation of intermediate.pem and cert.pem, as if you had run

```
cat intermediate.pem cert.pem > chain.pem
```

.crt is a file extension that's sometimes used for PEM files, so it's the same as .pem.

So in other words, I think chain.pem is the file you want. Try using it in place of domain.crt.

Once your certificate has been signed, you don't need the .csr file anymore. You may delete it.

Good luck!

Comment: I think I've solved it; it seems that the concatenation of cert.pem and intermediate.pem is the correct combination. It gave me an insecure connection warning from the web browser due to a missing configuration. Also, I think chain.pem is for validatinf the cert using the openssl command.